# Why is the cron ENV different from the user's ENV?

Tags: cron, shell, path

On a new Ubuntu install, a user's `PATH` is:

```
/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games
```

But in that same user's cron environment, it is:

```
/usr/bin:/bin
```

I looked at all the user's dot files in the home directory, nothing in there is changing the `PATH`.

What's changing the `PATH`? Why doesn't cron use that `PATH`?

Comment: you can do in this way "grep PATH /etc/crontab"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Regarding the question - why is this so - the manual page that explains it is `crontab(5)`, IOW the one accessible through `man 5 crontab` (not the default one in section 1). The cron daemon does not try to emulate a shell session, rather it sets up a clean, minimal environment for the cron jobs to run in, and then in turn allows the crontab file to set its own arbitrary environment variables. The newer cron daemon shipped with Debian also has several additional provisions for `pam_env` etc.

Comment: I wonder why /usr/local isn't considered clean and minimal whenin the crontab of a unprivileged user.

Comment: There is no real global default PATH on Unix systems - each user can and does have their own in their own shell settings, which are in arbitrary files that the cron daemon doesn't know about. Granted, /usr/local/bin is in FHS, http://www.pathname.com/fhs/2.2/fhs-4.9.html but I'm guessing the more conservative option (without it) is used for backwards compatibility. A related example is how RHEL/CentOS systems omit /usr/local/lib from the default library path, unlike Debian/Ubuntu systems which include it (through the required libc-bin package).

Answer (score 3):

Cron does not execute processes in a login shell. Because of this, all the typical scripts are not sourced when a process is executed.

Executing the process from within a login shell should replicate the user's environment.

Put something like this in a crontab and compare the two outputs:

```
*/1 * * * * /usr/bin/env > /tmp/env                                             
*/1 * * * * /usr/bin/bash -l -c /usr/bin/env > /tmp/bashenv
```

As you can see, `/tmp/bashenv` will have a whole slew of environment variables that `/tmp/env` does not. This is because `env` was invoked in a login shell using `bash -l`.